# Google Apps Script: Cannot find function insertText in object Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'd like to copy a Google Docs document and add text to the copy. This is my code:

```
function main() {
    var template = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_DOC_ID);
    var copy = template.makeCopy('copied file');
    var form = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    form.insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');
  }
```

When I run main(), I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot find function insertText in object Document. (line 5, file "Code")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put a text using `insertText()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Pattern 1:

When you want to put the text to the body, please modify as follows.

From:

```
form.insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');
```

To:

```
form.getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');
```

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to put the text to the paragraph, please modify as follows.

From:

```
form.insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');
```

To:

```
form.getBody().getParagraphs()[0].insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');
```

- In this case, the text is put to the first paragraph.

#### References:

- [insertText() of Class Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#inserttextoffset-text)
- [insertText() of Class Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#inserttextchildindex-text)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.